# Why does my FileSystemWatcher stop working after the first change in a subdirectory?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, filesystemwatcher

I have created a *FileSystemWatcher* like this:

```
public FileSystemWatcher CreateFileSystemWatcher(string directory)
{
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(directory);

    watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    // These are creating objects specific to my application to record changes.
    watcher.Created += OnCreated;
    watcher.Deleted += OnDeleted;
    watcher.Renamed += OnRenamed;
    watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
    watcher.Error += OnError;

    return watcher;
}
```

The watcher works perfectly as long as I only make changes in the directory that I provided in the constructor. But as soon as I make a change to a file in any subirectory, it records that change and then stops recording changes altogether.

There are some other questions on this site about *FileSystemWatchers*, but those issues seem to concern the internal buffer size of the watcher, which I don't think is the cause of my problem, as it occurs independently of number and frequency of changes.

**Here's another thing I noticed:**
The way my testing application ist set up is that I start it up, make a bunch of changes, and then press Enter in the console to print them all out. When I only make changes in the watcher's root path, the printing happens immediately, but when I make a change in a subdirectory, it takes a few seconds after I press Enter. Don't know what could cause this but I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: just for diagnostic purposes I'd start using the Error event as well and log any error events coming from that watcher.

Comment: Do you hold a reference of the created watcher instance? otherwise it is probably cleared by the gc.

Comment: @JohnnyQ Yes I hold a reference.

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek Good tip. Didn't get any errors unfortunately, but I will keep it in.