# What does "polling" mean in the context of watching for file changes?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, filesystemwatcher

I'm currently trying to get a FileSystemWatcher to work, as outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72909655/why-does-my-filesystemwatcher-stop-working-after-the-first-change-in-a-subdirect). During my research, I found a lot of answers and comments on this site describing the unreliability of this class. Instead, "polling" is mentioned in some places as a method of watching for changes, for example in [this (very old) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239988/filesystemwatcher-vs-polling-to-watch-for-file-changes/240008#240008). My question is what that means exactly.

Comment: There is a `Polling (Computer Science)` page on Wikipedia.

Comment: It means you fetch file metadata periodically and calculate diffs to the previous results.

Comment: It just means that code actively goes and enumerates the files in a directory and compares the list with the last time they were enumerated to see if anything has changed, rather than relying on a callback from the operating system to tell you that something has changed.

Comment: BTW: It has been quite some time since I have been using the FSW, but if you know its quirks and how to handle them I did not find it unreliable at all. But I encourage you to neither believe me nor anyone else. Better go and try for yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Polling means here that you regularly read for instance the last write-time of the files you want to watch and test if there is a difference. you could even read the file contents and compare it with a previous verison. Polling just means that you actively do the comparison instead of being notified.

Polling is best avoided for its cost. But if needed then it is needed.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)

Regarding FileSystemwatcher. It is not perfect but in my experience correct enough in the majority of the cases . I assume that all watchers in developer tools use that mechanism and it is for instance good enough there. I suggest to try it first for your purpose before polling.